# Render time only equal half of fps

Tags: c++, game-physics, directx-9

I'm working on a project that remakes mario 3 (NES). In my game loop, i face a strange thing. Here is my code:

```
 while (true)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        //Game logic
        c1++;
        _Mario.Update(1.0 / FPS);

        //Render
        _Timer.SetBeginTick();
        _LpD3dDevice9->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(102, 255, 255), 1.0f, 0);
        if (_LpD3dDevice9->BeginScene())
        {
            c2++;
            _Mario.Render();
            _LpD3dDevice9->EndScene();
        }
        _Keyboard->GetState();
        _Mario.Move(_Keyboard);
        _LpD3dDevice9->Present(0, 0, 0, 0);
        _Timer.SetCurrTick();
        _Timer.UpdateGameTIme();
        if (_Timer.ElapsedTime < (1.0 / FPS))
        {
            Sleep(1000.0 / FPS - _Timer.ElapsedTime * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Update function :

```
void ImageMove::Update(float t)
{
    _Image_X += _Image_Vx * t;
    _Image_Y -= _Image_Vy * t;
    _SpriteTimer.SetCurrTick();
    _SpriteTimer.UpdateGameTIme();
    if (_SpriteTimer.ElapsedTime >= 1.0 / ANIMATE_RATE)
    {
        if (_Image_Vx > 0) _Image_Right.Next(); //change to next sprite
        if (_Image_Vx < 0) _Image_Left.Next(); // change to next sprite
        _SpriteTimer.SetBeginTick();
    }
}
```

Render Function :

```
void ImageMove::Render()
{
    int vpx = _Image_X - 400;
    int VIEW_PORT_Y = _Image_Y + 500;
    _SpriteHandler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
    if (_Image_Vy > 0 && _Image_Vx_Last > 0) _Image_Jump_Right.Render(_Image_X, _Image_Y);
    else if (_Image_Vy > 0 && _Image_Vx_Last < 0) _Image_Jump_Left.Render(_Image_X, _Image_Y);
    else
    if (_Image_Vx > 0)_Image_Right.Render(_Image_X, _Image_Y);
    else if (_Image_Vx < 0)_Image_Left.Render(_Image_X, _Image_Y);
    else if (_Image_Vx_Last < 0)_Image_Left.Render(_Image_X, _Image_Y);
    else _Image_Right.Render(_Image_X, _Image_Y);
    _SpriteHandler->End();
}
```

I put c1 and c2 in my game loop to measure how many times Update and Render are called. I set fps = 60, while debuging, I let my game loop run for 5s, then set a breakpoint to view c1 and c2. The value of c1 = 320, and c2 = 160 ( = 1/2 c1 for sure, i have run it many times, so the times render is called only ~1/2 fps, i think with fps = 60, it should be ~300 for 5s, shoudn't It?).

If i debug with F10 (on Visual studio) , I can see a loop will execute with `_LpD3dDevice9->BeginScene()` success, and `_LpD3dDevice9->BeginScene()` in next loop always failed.

Is it error? Because i have tested on another small project, and c2 = 1/2 c1 too.
This problem cause an issue in my game. In Update() function, I change my sprite here, and draw it in `Render()` , so I always miss some sprite. Because It only render = 1/2 time game update.

If it is an error How can I fix my game loop? And if It is not an error, what can I do to prevent missing sprites?

P/S : sorry for bad English.

Comment: might want to post this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your DirectX initialization, it is likely that Present() is synced to the vsync of your monitor.
The Sleep() you put leaves no room for error, and Sleep typically is not very accurate. If it sleeps only a little longer, your next draw call may just have missed the next vsync, thus Present() will wait until another vsync comes by.

Try adding a little headroom to your Sleep() function by letting it sleep a few milliseconds less than what is required.